# thread pooling for http requests

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, http, concurrency

I have a few questions regarding architecture & performance for concurrency.

### Setup:

There is a JavaFX GUI where users can start various Tasks, which are themselves threaded tasks (`new Thread(new CustomTask<?>).start();`). These tasks do a loop for ~700k HTTP-requests and insert the processed return values if there are around 10k items in the prepared insert statement for the database. Their progress is displayed in the GUI (`ObservableList` items).

[image: Visualisation]

### Problem:

These tasks take a long time and the bottleneck seems to be the delay while waiting for the HTTP-response.
(DB inserts are done with auto-commit turned off in bulks of 10k prepared insert statements)

### Target:

Improve overall performance by having the requests in separate tasks/threads.

---

#### Q1:

Is it even reasonable to use threads here? How can I improve the performance in a other way?

#### Q2:

If threading is reasonable, how do I realize it?
I was thinking about having a global thread pool or `ExecutorService` where the request tasks are queued. When the response is available, it will be written to a synchronized list. If there are 10k+ objects in the list, execute a batch insert.

#### Q3:

How do I determine a good thread-pool size? How to distinguish threads?

`Thread.activeCount()` **returns 7** (current Thread Group)
`ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount()` **returns 13** (threads overall?)
`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` **returns 8**

I´ve read a few comments on multithreading and they all said that having more threads than cores does not necessarily improve performance (no “real” concurrency, timeslicing). I don´t know but if I had to guess I´d say the number 13 includes some GUI threads. I can´t seem to wrap my head around how to get a useful number for the ThreadPoolSize.

---

**I appreciate any hint on how to improve my application.**

Comment: If bottleneck is waiting for completion of IO to/from external entity (HTTP server), and there's not much of other useful work to do, you can't speed things up on client end. Perhaps, you can investigate why there's substantial response delay?

Comment: Since it is an external entity (not under my control) I can´t influence the response speed. If their servers have a bad day, I´m committed to waiting. My initial thought was to utilize the "waiting time" by sending more requests simultaneously.

Comment: Sending more requests to servers which can't handle what they already have _could_ be counter-productive ;) Or idea is to send requests to somewhere else?

Comment: The servers do handle the requests properly, it isn´t event that slow, just the slowest part of my application which I´m trying to improve ;)
I don´t mind the response delay, but by sending more requests I can process more answers by the time the server replied to the first ones sent.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use `ExecutorService`.

> I´ve read a few comments on multithreading and they all said that having more threads than cores does not necessarily improve performance (no “real” concurrency, timeslicing)

This is true for processes that don't sleep or wait/block, such as calculating prime numbers or processing images. In your case, HTTP client blocks until response returns, and until it happens thread remains idle. For HTTP request executor pool of size 50-100-200 is okay.

Pattern could be the following:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

// ...
// creating request and response future associated with it
Future<Response> responseFuture = es.submit(new Callable<Response>() {
    @Override
    public Response call() throws Exception {
        // request data by HTTP
        return response;
    }
});
customTask.push(responseFuture);
```

In a `customTask` object let's create a single thread service executor which will operate on list of `Response`s:

```
// create single pool executor in order to accept responses 
// one by one and at the order they're requested
ExecutorService customTaskService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 
List<Response> results = new ArrayList<>();    

// push() method
public void push(final Future<Response> responseFuture) {

     customTaskService.execute(new Runnable() {

         public void run() {
             try {
                 // response.get() will block inside this service thread
                 // though not affecting GUI thread
                 results.add(response.get(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); 
             } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                 // processing of a request failed
             }
             if (results.size() > MAX_SIZE) {
                 // make inserts to DB
                 results.clear();
             }
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: You need to use a concurrent data structure for `results` or synchronize on it. Your answer is also not very fault tolerant as you don't provide any timeout for the `response.get()`. I could go on and on about how bad an idea using plain old ExecutorService but I suppose this is an option.

Comment: @AdamGent I moved result collection into object where it's processed in a single service thread, so no synchronization is required now. And added timeout, thanks.

Comment: @AdamGent BTW, timeout can be defined on HTTP client when sending a request, as well as retry policy.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thanks for the clarification and the example. You stated 50-100-200 as pool sizes. Since this is a pretty wide range, what are the dependencies for the figures stated?

Comment: It depends on server and network configuration. For example, if http server is a single tomcat instance which is limited to 50 incoming connections, setting pool size more than 50 doesn't make sense. If the server is presented by distributed system behind dispatcher/load balancer, thousands of connections can be open in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

> Q1

First it is unclear what you need to respond back to the client with. Do you have to talk to the database to send back a response?

If you don't it is the Pub/Sub pattern (ie its fire and forget) then message queues or any pub/sub systems are ideal and scale far better than using a plain `ExecutorService`. Some examples are [AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), JMS, [Redis Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) and many many more.

You can do pub/sub with a reply to the client but this generally requires nonblocking client connections like WebSockets, Comet and is fairly complicated to setup.

> Q2 and Q3

If your problem is you DO need to reply to the client then it follows the Request/Reply pattern which is a harder problem to scale.

Some libraries that do this well are on the JVM are [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) which follows the command and bulkhead pattern which gives configurable and fault tolerant Request/Reply along with [request collapsing](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#RequestCollapsing) which I believe solves your: "*If there are 10k+ objects in the list, execute a batch insert.*"

Figuring out the proper pool size is actually fairly complicated for blocking operations. For nonblocking (ie cpu bound or in memory processing) its simply the available processors but this is not the case for you since your connecting to a database and probably using a blocking IO servlet container.

To figure out the proper pool size for blocking operations you will have use metrics and monitoring which Hystrix provides out of the box. You also should be aware of your downstream dependencies. For example if your database can only handle 200 concurrent connections you do not want a thread pool that talks to the database bigger than 200.

Comment: I agree that technologies you mentioned is much better for large applications, but they need so many additional things like installing and setting up MQ services/servers, creating message shemas, serializing/marshalling objects and other enterprise stuff.

Comment: You proposed messaging system, who will be consuming messages from the messaging system? Are you suggesting to add a server component that will consume message (http request) from gui and reply back message (http response) to gui? that is quite different architecture than what OP described.

Comment: BTW, thanks a lot for Nystrix link. I think I'll find it useful in projects I do at work.

Comment: @kr.pradeep you can publish the messages and have them picked up by the same server you like. You can also use an embedded message queue if a separate infrastructure piece is not allowed (an example of an embedded queue-like system would be akka). One of the advantages to an external pub/sub system is that you don't loose messages when a server is shutdown and you can boot other servers up for elastic load balancing along with many other things.

Comment: @AdamGent I´m not sure if I understand. The database is just for storage, I´m basically scraping an external database via their public API (returns `JSON` objects) and store the results in my own. Request -> collect xx k responses -> store. Also: each task has one database connection, which is why I´m collecting the results instead of inserting a row for each response. Thank you for the links, I´ll have a look.